# SignatureDoesNotMatch with Google's serviceAccounts.signBlob API

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to generated a signed URL to an object stored on Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

### Attempt 1: try the API using the API Explorer

For this, I am trying to sign the blob/object as defined in the following:

```
GET


<expiration time>
/<bucket name>/<object/blob name>
```

I first tried Google's serviceAccounts.signBlob API as discussed in the following page:

https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/signBlob

> A base64-encoded string.

*Note, as mentioned in the API documentation on the above-linked page, I pass a base64 representation of the blob I want to sign, to the API.*

The API's response has the following structure where it contains the `signedBlob` key:

```
{
  "keyId": "...",
  "signedBlob": "..."
}
```

then I generated a signed URL using the obtained signed blob as the following:

```py
encoded_signedBlob = base64.b64encode(signedBlob)
signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/{}?" \
             "GoogleAccessId={}&" \
             "Expires={}&" \
             "Signature={}".format(
    bucket_name, blob_name, 
    service_account_email, 
    expiration, 
    encoded_signedBlob)
```

and when I paste that signed URL in the browser to download the blob, I get the following error:

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>GET <bucket name> <blob/object name></StringToSign>
</Error>
```

### Attempt 2: try python libraries

Then I tried to implement it in python as the following, but still getting the same error.

```py
# -------------
# Part 1: obtain access token using the authorization flow discussed at:
# https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials
# -------------
client_service_account = "..."
access_token = build(
    serviceName='iamcredentials',
    version='v1',
    http=http
).projects().serviceAccounts().generateAccessToken(
    name="projects/{}/serviceAccounts/{}".format(
        '-',
        service_account_email),
    body=body
).execute()["accessToken"]

credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, "MyAgent/1.0", None)

# -------------
# Part 2: sign the blob
# -------------
service = discovery.build('iam', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
name = 'projects/.../serviceAccounts/...'
encoded = base64.b64encode(blob)
sign_blob_request_body = {"bytesToSign": encoded}
request = service.projects().serviceAccounts().signBlob(name=name, body=sign_blob_request_body)
response = request.execute()
keyId = response["keyId"]
signedBlob = response["signature"]


# -------------
# Part 3: generate signed URL
# -------------
encoded_signedBlob = base64.b64encode(signedBlob)
signed_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/{}?" \
             "GoogleAccessId={}&" \
             "Expires={}&" \
             "Signature={}".format(
    bucket_name, blob_name, 
    service_account_email, 
    expiration, 
    encoded_signedBlob)
```

Comment: How are you constructing the SignedURL?

Comment: Show the string that you signed. The error message tells you what is wrong `<StringToSign>GET ... ...</StringToSign>` Include that also. The string that Google built to verify does not match the string built and signed. The error message shows you exactly what to build.

Comment: @JohnHanley Updated my question by adding more details. You may notice the `StringToSign` I am using is equal to what is given in the error message. So its not clear from the message what causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look to the implementation of this using the [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-get-object-python), you could give it a try, remember to include google-cloud-storage in your requirements.txt and a service account as specified in the code sample for python